# Is there a formula for this string of numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can see the pattern, but how do I check if this is true for all numbers up to, say a million or more?

$1+2=3$

$4+5+6=7+8$

$9+10+11+12=13+14+15$

$16+17+18+19+20=21+22+23+24$

Comment: As example for curiosity: there are similar formulas with squares: try to find the pattern: $$10^2+11^2+12^2=13^2+14^2;\\21^2+22^2+23^2+24^2 = 25^2+26^2+27^2;\\ 36^2+37^2+\ldots+40^2=41^2+42^2+\ldots+44^2;\\55^2+56^2+\ldots+60^2=61^2+62^2+\ldots+65^2;\\\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course:
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
\sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+n}k = \dfrac{(n+1)(2n^2+n)}{2} = \dfrac{(n+1)n(2n+1)}{2};\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=n^2+n+1}^{n^2+2n}k = \dfrac{n(2n^2+3n+1)}{2} = \dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{2}.\tag{2}
$$

RHS-sof $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal.

---

Therefore one can write more generally:
$$
\sum_{k=n^2}^{n^2+n}k = \sum_{k=n^2+n+1}^{n^2+2n}k,
$$
or 
$$
n^2+(n^2+1)+\ldots+(n^2+n) = (n^2+n+1)+(n^2+n+2)+\ldots + (n^2+2n).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(n^2+k)=(n+1)n^2+\sum_{k=0}^nk=n(n^2+n)+\sum_{k=1}^nk=\sum_{k=1}^n(n^2+n+k)$$